# hibernate search analysis not performed on the field @IndexedEmbedded

Tags: search, lucene, hibernate-search

```
@Indexed
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @DocumentId
    private Long id;    

    @Field
    @AnalyzerDiscriminator(impl = LanguageDiscriminator.class) // "de", GermanAnalyzer
    private String lang;               

    @IndexedEmbedded    
    private User user;

}

@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = GermanAnalyzer.class)
public class User implements Serializable {        

    @DocumentId   
    private Long id;           

    @Field
    private String firstName;

  }
```

firstName field will be analyzed in the index User, and will not be analyzed in the index Event.
This is the correct behavior or not?

Answer (score 0):

It will be analyzed in the *Event* index but the field name will be *user.firstName* in that case. You can override the default prefix by using the otional attributes of *@IndexedEmbedded*.

Comment: Analysis of the field is not happening! It is added to the index 'Event' under the name 'user.firstName', but without the analysis!